# Pass data across loop in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function that consists of a `"Map"` (looping over an Array in the input), and then a number of tasks carried out in sequence with all the results. However, in the last step I'd *also* like to be able to access some of the original input data, that was not used in the intermediate steps. How should I best do this?

What I have tried so far:

- Passing all input data through the map tasks. This however fails quickly, because there is a limit on how large results can be passed between functions, and with hundreds of iteration the original input is multiplied hundreds of times.
- Using `Parallel` state, and add an empty state in one branch of the parallel execution that simply passes the input on, while all of the iteration happens in the other. This feels like a hack, because my step structure now poorly reflects the actual logic of the code.

What would be the “right” way to do this?

```
                     Iterate
                     over Fiz
                     +--------+   +-------------+    +------------+
{                    | +---+  |   |             |    |            |
  Foo: "Bar", --> -------+ |  +---+      Y      +----+     Z      |
  Fiz: [...],        | +-+ |      |             |    |            |
}                    +-----+      +-------------+    +------------+
```

*In box Z above, I want to have access to both 'Foo', and the output of Y*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that each step in the SFN has access to the original input, but you have to explicitly state insert them using `Parameters`. All the input is available in `$$.Execution.Input`.

When using `Parameters`, you are overriding all other input, so you will *also* have to define what you want to pass along from the previous step. In other words: If Y is passing `{fruit: "apple"}` to Z, and you want Z to see both that and the original input `{Foo: "Bar"}` , you would add the following to the Z step in SFN:

```json
{
    "Parameters": {
        "Foo.$": "$$.Execution.Input.Foo",
        "fruit.$": "$.apple"
}
```

Note the double `$$` in the first case, and the single `$` in the second.